# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid json request

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, ethereumjs

my deploy.js script returns this error :

```
"(node:6636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid json request
    at D:\kickstart\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\index.js:15:620862
    at e.i.onreadystatechange (D:\kickstart\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\index.js:15:775522)
    at e.t.dispatchEvent (D:\kickstart\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\index.js:1:152983)
    at e._setReadyState (D:\kickstart\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\index.js:15:780284)
    at e._onHttpResponseEnd (D:\kickstart\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\index.js:15:783369)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\kickstart\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\index.js:15:782627)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:6636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6636) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."
```

My deploy.js file is :

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledFactory = require('./build/CompaignFactory.json')

const provider =  new HDWalletProvider(
  'hat stick simple coyote xxxx only yyyy crush cook zzzzz coconut patient', //Type your memonic
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
  .deploy({ data: compiledFactory.bytecode })
  .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

};
deploy();
```

any help please?

Comment: You should by the least indicate which line in your script throws this error (and probably add some of your debug-efforts as well)!

Comment: node command output does not specify which line is causing the error :) I pasted all the error message. have a nice day!

Comment: Then you should by the least do some basic debugging and figure out which line is causing it. For example, put everything in a `try`/`catch` clause, or just add a `console.log` after every line and see how far you've got. This purpose of this site is not for you dump your problems here and get others to debug them for you.

Comment: my code uses only one json request so its clear where the problem is located :)

Comment: What is "json request"???

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.
This is a known bug in **web3** and it has been fixed in version **1.0.0-beta.48**.
You can check here for more details [github link](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2447)

***Solution***: Update the web3 npm dependency to **1.0.0-beta.48**